# Retrofit Ford 460 For Fuel Injection

Tags: fuel-system, carburetor, fuel-injection

I have a '78 Pioneer Jet Boat with a Ford 460 Big Block V8 as the power plant.
Right now it has a Holley carb on it. We just started toying with the idea of converting it from carbureted to fuel injected. We know we'll need a new intake manifold, ECU, etc but we're wondering what might be the cheapest way in going about this.

**Can I walk over to my local Pick n Pull looking for an old Ford pickup that has a 460 in it and pull the fuel injection system out of that and slap it on my boats motor?

When doing this, what do I need to keep an eye out for? I'm sure EFI intake manifolds might have changed ever so slightly between years. How can I be sure that the EFI system I rip out of the donor will bolt right onto my boats motor?**

Also after talking to the guy who was working on fuel injectors for me was saying I should try to find a fuel injected vehicle that has OBD-I instead of OBD-II because of sensors, and the lack of a transmission.

Comment: Just something to think about if you use automotive system.  A quick search shows several places offering conversion kits. All the sites mentioned use of USCG (Coast Guard) approved fuel pumps, fuel lines, and spark arrestors,

Comment: What mods do you have on your engine right now? Or is it pretty much stock? Also, was this a marine engine to begin with or was it pulled from a car and used as a boat engine? If so, which car or truck (year/model)?

Comment: @Paulster2 I'm almost certain it is a marine engine. Being that it was installed in the boat when it was first purchased back in '78. It is pretty much stock. Basset headers.

Comment: What is the goal of putting EFI on your BBF? If you think it's going to make more HP, you are probably mistaken. A carburetor is going to be easier to run/tune and make more HP than an el-cheapo EFI system will be. If you are willing to step up to FAST or some other aftermarket EFI, you'll make cleaner power and probably more of it. And before you ask, I'm a big fan of EFI ... it's going to be terribly hard to find a junk yard EFI system you can just plant on your 460 and have it run right. Lots of stuff you'd have to do to make it right. I'm not a Ford guy, though ... I could be wrong.

Comment: @gh0st , Unless this is a hobby project, its pretty much waste of time and money to convert a carb engine to EFI , the only advantage in the real world is 15% more fuel efficiency and better emissions.